# Diffeomorphism of sphere

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Is possible to define a diffeomorphism between $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $1=x^2-y^2$?

Any hint? I try to draw the surface but I have problem with the points $(0,1,0)$ of the sphere for example.

Comment: Homeomorphism preserve connectedness. So ...

Comment: In addition to connectedness, the sphere is compact and the hyperbolic cylinder isn't. So it is not even homeomorphic to either of its two connected components.

Answer (score 2):

No. The sphere is connected, while the surface described in space by $1=x^2-y^2$  (the variable $z$ just happens to be absent, meaning that $z$ ranges over $\Bbb R$) is not. In fact, this surface has 2 connected components, indexed by the sign of $x$. So, the given surfaces are not diffeomorphic (not even homeomorphic).

Comment: I think it only has 2 components, it's a cylinder over a hyperbola.

Comment: Oopsie. You're right, two components. I was thinking of $x^2-y^2 = \pm 1$.